# Excel Spreadsheet - How to remove white space characters from text from an entire row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to know how I can format the text for an entire row in Microsoft Excel. I would like to remove white space characters between text from an entire row.

This is what I have right now:
[image: This]

Essentially, this is what I would like to achieve:
[image: this]

My inputs are set as text. If I use the Find and Replace feature, then 0s will be removed only if it is located at the beginning of the input. How can I remove all white spaces using the Find and Replace feature, whilst still keeping 0s at the beginning of the text value?

Comment: The answer is perhaps too simple: Select the entire row and do "Find and Replace".

Comment: Can you show us the data, and which character you want to remove?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @harrymc This works, but if the text has a 0 at the beginning it will be removed after replacing the spaces. Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1674550/edit) your post with some examples of what you're trying to do. There is no mention of spaces or `0`s in your post, so how can we help?

Comment: Your inputs are probably stored as text at the beginning, when you remove spaces those became numbers and numbers are not displayed with leading zero. What do you want: keep leading 0? Keep storing as text? Your description suggests you need find & replace, while you tagged your question as "worksheet-function", which one do you need? Please edit your question clarifying what exactly you need.

Comment: @MátéJuhász My inputs are stored as text. But when I use Find and Replace to remove the spaces, any input with a leading 0 gets removed. I have removed "worksheet-function" tag from the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods you could use:

#### `SUBSTITUTE` function

You can use the [`SUBSTITUTE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) to create a new column that replaces all spaces with an empty string, removing all spaces from the text:

[image]

Which results in:

[image]

#### Find and replace

If you remove the spaces with Find & Replace, Excel by default removes any leading 0's and interprets the cell as a number.
Setting the number formatting to Text is not sufficient. Instead prepend a single quote to the cell and then use the Find & Replace functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the Range and right click- **Format Cells**...- **Custom** set to: **0000000000**- Then **Replace** all space:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `TEXT()` function to set the formatting structure, e.g.:

`=TEXT(A1,"0000000000")`

For the whitespace removal, you can use a catchall function like:

`=CLEAN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), " ")))`

This accounts for non-breaking spaces as well as standard spaces and non-print characters.

If you need the output to be a numeric datatype, I *believe* you can wrap it with a `VALUE()` function (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

The advantage of using these methods would be that it's purely formulaec (no UI or dialog window access needed).